# Redeem Code Option in Payment method not showing in my app. Android Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

The redeem code option in payment method list is not showing in my app. Screenshot below is from google play billing documentation but the option did not appear in my app. It's already been a week since I added and activated a promotion in the play console, still the option does not appear.

Edit: My google pay account is from the Philippines, btw. I am not sure if it has something to do with the locality or country.

[image: Redeem code option as seen on their documentation]

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo

[image: My Payment Screen]

Comment: have you got solution?

Comment: Did anyone got the solution?

Comment: I need this answer, still, no answer is here.

Comment: This is still a issue. Does anybody have solution?